# Write an addon for dolphin android browser

Tags: android, browser, add-on

I been searching for a while to get any reference to wite a addon for dolphin browser. Couldnt find any. Can anyone just point to any relavent website for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to be a partner:

http://dolphin.com/partner/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.